# Каким образом взять значение введёное в окне Text менялось и в sk

Tags: python, tkinter, текст

Товарищи эксперты,подскажите нубу. Каким образом числовое значение которое мы ввели в w2 = Text становилось значением sk.То есть если например я в окне программы w2 = Text под названием Данные ввёл число 2354 то это число тут же поменялось в sk на 2354. Мне нужно что-бы это работало без всяких кнопок.

```py
from tkinter import *


w1 = Tk()

w1.title("Тест")
w1.geometry("600x350")
w1.resizable(width=False, height=False)

w2 = Text(width=70, height=2, bg="#F8F8FF", fg='black', font='Arial 11', wrap=WORD).place(x=10, y=36)
w2 = Label(text="Данные", font="20").place(x=90, y=6)

sk = 593336 #sk должно становиться тем значение,которое мы ввели в окне w2 = Text запущенной программы

w1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов мы вводим любые значения и он их сохраняет в переменную

```
from tkinter import *


def func(event):
    global sk
    try:
        sk = int(w2.get("0.0", END))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    print(sk)


w1 = Tk()

w1.title("Тест")
w1.geometry("600x350")
w1.resizable(width=False, height=False)

w2 = Text(width=70, height=2, bg="#F8F8FF", fg='black', font='Arial 11', wrap=WORD)
w2.place(x=10, y=36)
w2.bind("<Key>", func)
l2 = Label(text="Данные", font="20").place(x=90, y=6)

sk = 593336  # sk должно становиться тем значение,которое мы ввели в окне w2 = Text запущенной программы

w1.mainloop()
```